# Assigning to a byte array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, variable-assignment

I have a byte array I want to assign as follows:

- First byte specifies the length of the string: `(byte)string.length()`
- 2nd - Last bytes contain string data from `string.getBytes()`

Other than using a for loop, is there a quick way to initialize a byte array using bytes from two different variables?

Comment: Can you guarantee that your strings will always be < 256 characters long (128 if you don't deal with sign bit)?

Comment: Yes I can, and can you elaborate on dealing with the sign bit?

Comment: @Anon: `byte` is an unsigned type in Java.

Comment: Bytes in Java are signed values. When converted to an `int`, they'll be sign-extended. So you have to mask the sign-extended value to get the range 0..255: `b & 0xFF`

Comment: @R Bernrose - really? so the JLS is wrong? http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.1

Comment: @Anon I'm doing this to convert a String to bits for steganography purposes. Will I have problems, having converted my stream of bits back into a byte array, getting my String out again?

Comment: @Anon: yes, but not in this case :-).  Sometimes I wish you could d/v comments.

Comment: @Anon: Sorry, my bad - I meant to address that to @R.Bemrose.

Comment: @Anon: A-yi-yi... I guess this is what I get for switching back and forth between Java and C#.  C#'s bytes are unsigned (sbyte being its signed type).  Forgot that Java doesn't do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `System.arrayCopy()` to copy your bytes:

```
String x = "xx";
byte[] out = new byte[x.getBytes().length()+1];
out[0] = (byte) (0xFF & x.getBytes().length());
System.arraycopy(x.getBytes(), 0, out, 1, x.length());
```

Though using something like a `ByteArrayOutputStream` or a `ByteBuffer` like other people suggested is probably a cleaner approach and will be better for your in the long run :-)

Comment: This is probably simpler than using a library class for an operation this straightforward.  One comment is that the `(0xFF & ...)` operation is completely redundant when going TO a byte.  The `(byte)` cast truncates in the same way.  It's only when going back to an integer that you care.

Comment: Ok, granted. I was thinking, better safe then sorry, right? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

How about [`ByteBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) ?

**Example :**

```
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(string.getBytes().length +1 );
    bb.put((byte) string.length());
    bb.put(string.getBytes());
```

Comment: This is the right approach, but requires some comments. First, it needs to check the string's length before blindly casting to `byte`. Second, it should use the variant of `String.getBytes()` that takes a character set.

Comment: @Anon agree with your comments +1 :) @fredley if you are following please take care of this

Comment: It would be nice to include the code to get to what the OP asked for: a byte array.

Answer (score 2):

While `ByteBuffer` is generally the best way to build up byte arrays, given the OP's goals I think the following will be more robust:

```
public static void main(String[] argv)
throws Exception
{
   String s = "any string up to 64k long";

   ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(bos);
   out.writeUTF(s);
   out.close();

   byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

   ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
   DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(bis);

   String s2 = in.readUTF();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html)?